# Unable to stop asp.net core Windows Service when Kestrel receives requests

Tags: c#, service, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

We are using asp.net core running on .net 4.5.1 as Windows Service. Kestrel is used as web server (Kestrel version is 1.1.2).
It was configured in accordance with [Host an ASP.NET Core app in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service). We also using SignalR running on OWIN.

The problem occurs when two events occur simultaneously: Windows Service is stopping and some new web requests were received by Krestel. If these conditions are met, then Windows service stops responding and hangs.

> Windows could not stop the Topshelf.Host service on Local Computer.
> Error 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.

*Confuguration code:*

```
var port = Global.Settings.Port;
var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()                  
                .UseKestrel()                   
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://+:" + port);

if (runAsService)
 {                    
       hostBuilder.UseContentRoot(directoryPath);
       Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(directoryPath);
 }
 else
 {                    
     hostBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
 }

var host = hostBuilder.Build();
if (runAsService)
{                 
    host.RunAsCustomService();
}
else
{                    
      host.Run();
}

public static class WebHostServiceExtensions
{
    public static void RunAsCustomService(this IWebHost host)
    {
        var webHostService = new CustomWebHostService(host);
        ServiceBase.Run(webHostService);
    }
}
internal class CustomWebHostService : WebHostService
{
    public CustomWebHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
    {
    }

//...
}
```

**Further investigation revealed** that unhandled exception occured when disposing _host in [WebHostService.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/1.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices/WebHostService.cs).

```
protected sealed override void OnStop()
{
    _stopRequestedByWindows = true;
    OnStopping();
    _host?.Dispose();
    OnStopped();
}
```

As described below, it raises an exception "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4082 EBUSY resource busy or locked"

## The Question is:

Is there a way to avoid such an error and prevent Windows Service hangs? E.g. stop Krestel before _host disposing or prevent new incoming connection in OnStopping event.

Stacktrace:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException:
> Error  **-4082 EBUSY resource busy or locked**
> in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.loop_close(UvLoopHandle
> handle)     in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvLoopHandle.ReleaseHandle()
> in System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalDispose()     in
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> in System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()     in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object
> parameter)
>
> in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.d__51.MoveNext()
> in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32
> millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.Dispose()
> in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Dispose()     in
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Dispose()
> in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Dispose()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException:
> Error -4082 EBUSY resource busy or locked    in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.loop_close(UvLoopHandle
> handle)     in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvLoopHandle.ReleaseHandle()
> in System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalDispose()     in
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> in System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()     in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object
> parameter)
>
> в
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.d__51.MoveNext()

Comment: looks like a problem with Kestrel. Try to raise an issue in [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EBUSY exceptions thrown from KestrelServer.Dispose() [will be fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/1798) in the 2.0 release of Kestrel. I think the reason your service is hanging is because `_host?.Dispose()` is throwing which prevents `OnStopped();` from being called inside the `OnStop()` method.

In the meantime, swallowing the exception to ensure `OnStopped();` always gets called should allow the service to be stopped. Make sure to build a new WebHost if you want to restart the server.